# Hash Url in ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, cloudpagesurl

I have a cloudpage where this page redirect from company's marketing site with using an email as variable. I write a code in JavaScript code where it redirect to cloudpage url with email where email is encrypted.

```html
    <p>Click the following link to visit the encrypted URL:</p>
    <a id="encryptedLink" href="#" target="_blank">Encrypted Link</a>
    
    <script>
        // JavaScript code for encrypting the parameter and constructing the URL
        function encryptParameter(parameter, secretKey) {
            const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(parameter, secretKey);
            return encodeURIComponent(ciphertext.toString());
        }
    
        const parameter = "test@email.com";
        const r_url = "https://cloud.mc.test.com/test-cloudpage"
        const secretKey = "test_encrypted";
        const encryptedParameter = encryptParameter(parameter, secretKey);
    
        // Construct the encrypted URL
        const encryptedURL = "https://cloud.mc.barnebys.com/test-hash-url123?Email=" + encryptedParameter+ "&r_url=" + r_url;
    
        // Set the href attribute of the anchor tag
        const encryptedLink = document.getElementById("encryptedLink");
        encryptedLink.href = encryptedURL;
    </script>
```

At cloudpage, I am getting the email by decrypting the parameter with javascript code.

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
    <script runat="client">
      function decryptParameter(encryptedParameter, secretKey) {
        const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedParameter, secretKey);
        return bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      }
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      
      const encryptedParameter = urlParams.get("Email");
      
      var secretKey = "test_encrypted";
      var decryptedParameter = decryptParameter(encryptedParameter, secretKey);
      
      console.log(decryptedParameter)
    
    </script>
```

The problem is, I can not move the email in serverside javascript or ampscript. How can I do it? Or is there any other way that will be helpful for me to solve the issue?

Comment: The email address provided on the landing page - is it an existing contact/subscriber in Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Yes, it provided on the landing page, not for all time, sometimes new user in here and sometimes existing subscriber in here.

Comment: Can you decrypt email paramter in ssjs? Using DecryptSymmetric()

Comment: No, because the email comes from user's end.